# How to switch between externalized messages in Spring with thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, thymeleaf

**Spring + thymeleaf**

I want to display the message from `Messages_pl.properties` or `Messages_en.properties` depending on the need. And here's my problem as I don't know what to do when I want to view a message from the second file ( `Messages_pl.properties` is taken into account by default).

To access resource bundles by using specified basename I added the bean below to my @Configuration class:

```
@Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("Messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

`Messages_pl.properties`:

```
welcome.message=siemanko
```

`Messages_en.properties`:

```
welcome.message=hello
```

The fragment of my html file where I use this property:

```
 <h1 th:text="#{message.welcome}"></h1>
```

Result: `siemanko`

what should I do to get the result as `hello`?

Answer (score 1):

You can define on the same file Messages.properties the following :

```
welcome.message.pl=siemanko
welcome.message.en=hello
```

Then you can can a local resolver to make your project capable of determining the locale which is currently being used :

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    return new CookieLocaleResolver();
}
```

Then add an interceptor of your language :

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
}
```

After that its simple to switch between languages , you just have to change the value of parameter lang on your link :

```
localhost:8080/your_page?lang=pl // will show siemanko on your page
localhost:8080/your_page?lang=en // will show hello on your page
```